# kubectl command to find a particular pod status as ready

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I wanted to hit a command which searches pod with the service name and identify its pod's status as "Ready"

I tried some of the commands but it does not work and it does not search with service-name.

```
kubectl get svc | grep my-service | --output="jsonpath={.status.containerStatuses[*].ready}" | cut -d' ' -f2
```

I tried to use the loop also, but the script does not give the desired output.

Can you please help me figure out the exact command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every service create a endpoints which contain the podIp and other info for service. you can just use that `endpoints` to get you pods.  . it will show you the ready pod for your `my-service`.

use this command:

```
kubectl get endpoints -n <Name_space> <service_name> -o json | jq -r 'select(.subsets != null) | select(.subsets[].addresses != null) | .subsets[].addresses[].targetRef.name'
```

for you the command will be:

```
kubectl get endpoints my-service -o json | jq -r 'select(.subsets != null) | select(.subsets[].addresses != null) | .subsets[].addresses[].targetRef.name'
```

you can run the script for getting the pod status

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for podname in $(kubectl get endpoints my-service -o json | jq -r 'select(.subsets != null) | .subsets[].addresses[].targetRef.name')
do
kubectl get pods -n demo  $podname  -o json | jq -r ' select(.status.conditions[].type == "Ready") | .status.conditions[].type ' | grep -x Ready

done
```

Comment: @sagarverma i have updated. it can you try now?

Comment: sure..will try now

Comment: Yes. I understood and it is giving an error when the pod is not ready and returning the pod name  But is there a way we can also able to get the status of READY parameter of pod. Since I have the requirement to check the status of pod.

Comment: `kc get pods   -o json | jq -r '.items[] | select(.status.conditions[].type=="Ready") | .metadata.name '` this one will show you every pod that is ready in default namespace

Comment: @sagarverma i have updated my ans again  with what you need . can you please take look now?

Comment: I used this command which gives me Ready status. But the pod name is dynamic and I wanted to pass that dynamic pod name to this command.: kubectl get pod <pod-name> --output="jsonpath={.status.containerStatuses[*].ready}".  So that full command will get the pod name and return the Ready status. Can you help me to figure out how can it be acieved?

Comment: @sagarverma with this new one i think you are going to get what you want.

Comment: Emon. Still, both commands is giving the pod name instead of Ready status.

Comment: i have added a script which one is going to give you the status only . please look into that if that one is useful

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you want to find if specific `Pod` connected to specific `Endpoint` - is in `"Ready"` status .

Using `JSON PATH` you can display all `Pods` in specific `namespace` with their status:

```
$ kubectl get pod -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.phase}{"\n"}{end}'
```

If you are looking for status for `Pods` connected to specific `Endpoint`, you can use below script:

```
#!/bin/bash

endpointName="web-1"

for podName in $(kubectl get endpoints  $endpointName -o=jsonpath={.subsets[*].addresses[*].targetRef.name}); do
    if [ ! -z $podName ]; then
        kubectl get pod -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.phase}{"\n"}{end}' | grep $podName
    fi
done

for podName in $(kubectl get endpoints  $endpointName -o=jsonpath={.subsets[*].notReadyAddresses[*].targetRef.name}); do
    if [ ! -z $podName ]; then
        kubectl get pod -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.status.phase}{"\n"}{end}' | grep $podName
    fi
done
```

Please note that you need to change `Endpoint` name to your needs, in above example I use `web-1` name.

If this response doesn't answer your question, please specify your exact purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Very easy and native command:

```bash
kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running
```